# How to search Elasticsearch index list by index name (wild card)

Tags: elasticsearch

My Elasticsearch instance, there are massive indexes, some are date suffixed some are not.

I know `GET _cat/indices` can give me all indexes, but that's too many.

Is there any way I can get all index list which begins with `call-` in the index name?

E.g. The result I want is: (Search index itself, not the index doc)

```
call-staging-201804
call-staging-201805
call-dev-201804
call-dev-201805
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

YEs you can use [multiple indicies](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) query

> Most APIs that refer to an index parameter support execution across
>   multiple indices, using simple test1,test2,test3 notation (or _all for
>   all indices). It also support wildcards, for example: test* or *test
>   or te*t or *test*, and the ability to "exclude" (-), for example:
>   test*,-test3.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index1,index2/_search?q=search'
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/call-*/_search?q=search'
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_search?q=search'
```

But be careful with this since it will take more time

Comment: Sorry, I mean I search index names itself. Sorry, will update my question

Comment: @Xin get it what you want. I would recommend you to get all and maybe cache. Otherwise explain usecase